# weird shadow lines in shaded mode with texture enabled

Tags: texturing, error, shadows

I am learning modelling with **imphenzia youtube channel**, and have applied same settings for low poly modelling.

**I am seeing weird unexpected shadow lines visible from only some specific angles.**

they changes when i change shadow angles in viewport shading options shadows direction.

I don't know shadow source or what is causing it, so i can delete it.

[image][image]